# How to compute the residue of $f(z)=\frac{n/z}{z^{n}-1}$ to be $-n$ at $z=0$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, complex

How to get residue of $f(z)=\frac{n/z}{z^{n}-1}$ with correct residue of $-n$ at zero?

It works it out just fine at 1 with:

```
Residue[(n/z/(z^n - 1)), {z, 1}]
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143173/discussion-on-question-by-onepound-how-to-compute-the-residue-of-fz-fracn-z); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I agree with @user64494 that this is not a complete duplicate and further the closure of the question. However I'm grateful for time and useful information all have contributed nevertheless. If I understand the system correctly the question might be automatically removed in time especially as it is now likely to attract downvotes - rather unfortunate considering it might help somebody else. TTFN

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the comment: `the residue at z=1 is clearly wrong`

If a function, $f(z)$, has a pole of order $k$ at $z=z_0$ then

$$
\begin{equation}
\text{Res}(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} \left[(z-z_0)^k f(z) \right]\Bigg|_{z=z_0}
\end{equation}
$$

Ok, so let's consider the function -which is the example in the OP with $n=1$

$$
\begin{equation}
f = - \frac{1}{z(1-z)}
\end{equation}
$$

The above has a pole of order $1$ at $z=0$ and a pole of order $1$ at $z=1$. Hence, we compute explicitly

$$
\text{Res}(f,0) = \frac{1}{(1-1)!} \left((z-0)^1(-)\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-z} \right)\Bigg|_{z=0} = - 1 
$$

and also

$$
\text{Res}(f,1) = \frac{1}{(1-1)!} \left((z-1)^1(-)\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-z} \right)\Bigg|_{z=1} =  1 
$$

And likewise for higher values of $n$.

So, when `Mathematica` computes

```
Residue[n/(z (z^n - 1)) /. n -> 1, {z, 0}]
Residue[n/(z (z^n - 1)) /. n -> 1, {z, 1}]
```

as

> `-1`

> `1`

it is indeed correct.

Then, all the methods agree.

@Artes suggested

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[Residue[n/(z (z^n - 1)), {z, 0}], {n, 10}],
  n]
```

which returns

> `-n`

and is the same as

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n >= 1, 
 Simplify@SeriesCoefficient[n/(z (z^n - 1)), {z, 0, -1}]]
```

from the linked question. Credits are to @Carl Woll.

Hopefully the above offers some clarity and will stop the war of the comments.

Comment: `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n >= 1, 
 Simplify@SeriesCoefficient[n/(z (z^n - 1)), {z, 0, -1}]]` is somewhat more exact.

Comment: I'd like to notice  `SeriesCoefficient[n/(z (z^n - 1)), {z, 0, -1}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n >= 1]` returns `Piecewise[{{-n, Mod[0, n] == 0}}, 0]`.

Comment: @user64494 regarding your first comment, yes you are correct. my bad as I was copying and pasting. regarding your second comment take into consideration that `SeriesCoefficient[n/(z (z^n - 1)), {z, 0, -1}, 
  Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n >= 1] // FullSimplify` returns `-n`